# model.features_names_in not working for decision trees in Anaconda Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, scikit-learn, anaconda, jupyter, decision-tree

is there any way I can get the feature names of the decision tree model as defined below using sklearn or any other packages in the Anaconda Jupyter Notebook? I'm trying to work on this issue for a long time now, but have not been able to search for exact work through.

[Code snippet with the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPwxT.png)

[Latest Code for preparing model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vc4td.png)

[Code for running the model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LTJ2.png)

[Code for visualizing the DT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TIzHR.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please, don't show your error as image, copy it as code in the question. This will make easier to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use a Pandas dataframe with the feature names when you train your decision tree model instead of a Numpy array with no feature names.

[Scikit-learn decision tree documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier)

Comment: So, I tried using the method you suggested, but it didn't work for me. I used a pandas data frame with the string features names from the dataset on which I want to train the model. I'm posting the latest code snippets in the question above.